# Android: Changing a Original View class

Tags: java, android, android-view, gestureoverlayview

How can i edit a View class?

I want to change methods used by a *GestureOverlayView* , 
i opened the *GestureOverlayView.java* file (obtained by jumping inside of it from the Debugger) but nothing that i change is actually executed.
Is there any way to edit the class, or a better way like Overriding certain methods?

The specific change that i want to implement is no waiting delay after a "Single" gesture has been performed (It normally waits 700ms, so the user can make another stroke (theoretically) even when the mode is set to "Single" instead of "Multiple"). There also isn´t any method inside that helps me change that.

Thanks.

Comment: Just extend it like a normal java class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can subclass it like any normal Java class and Override the methods you want to change.

```
public class MyGestureOverlayView extends GestureOverlayView {
    ...
    @Override 
    public void cancelGesture() {
        // Add your own implementation 
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i tell the XML file to use the subclass instead of the GestureOverlayView?

Comment: Just type in the name of your custom view class with its package path as its prefix. You may have to build your project to get it to show.

Comment: Thanks, even though i am still having problems with changing the implementation of certain things because they use private methods and variables, i can atleast set the fadeoffset and fadeouttime to 0 (not related to custom class) so that the delay is gone (10-20ms instead of 720ms), i think ill just do that and look into an alternative for implementing a fadeout-effect.
Thanks for your help.